# Simplify GA[a].GA[b]+GA[b].GA[a] to 2 MT[a,b]

Tags: feyncalc

Does a FeynCalc command exist, that simplifies the expression

```
GA[a].GA[b]+GA[b].GA[a]
```

to

```
2 MT[a,b]
```

I've tried Calc, DiracSimplify and DiracTrick to no avail.

If not, how can I do it with vanilla Mathematica?

edit for clarification purposes.

`GA[mu]` refers to the GammaMatrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices). There exists an anticommutator relation that allows the anticommuter of two GammaMatrices with Minkowksi indices $\mu$ and $\nu$ to be simplified to the metric tensor element $\eta^{\mu\nu}$.

$\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = 2\eta^{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You need to use `DiracOrder` or `DiracSimplify` with the option `DiracCanonical` set to `True`.

Comment: You should post this as an answer as it is correct.